# Customizing Moodle

Tags: moodle

I am new to Moodle. I have spent quite enough time in searching for answers. So I am posinta long list of questions I have.

1. How do I add logo to  my moodle page ?
2. How do I add images to the courses ?
3. How do I change the color of the theme inside moodle ?
4. I don't want to assign roles for the course. I want assign roles to the participants during the login creation time ? How do I do ?
5. How do I add a video conferencing facility where I can invite lots of participants to watch the online video lectures ?
6. Is there any possibility to enable chat facility for students who attend the video lectures so they can ask questions online ?
7. Is there any way to integrate e-commerce with Moodle so I can charge students who want to enroll for a course ?
8. Is there any way to list course categories, courses and the teacher also ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please post only one question at a time. To get a positive response, be sure to show what you have tried, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You haven't stated a Moodle version, so I'm going to assume Moodle 2.6 (latest stable version).

1. Depends on the theme you have chosen (look on the settings page for your theme, under site admin > appearance > themes)
2. Turn on editing, drag+drop image onto the course page, choose the 'insert into course page' option (or add a label and insert an image into that)
3. Install the Essential theme - that should allow you to do what you want with the colour scheme - https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=theme_essential
4. Employ a developer to write a custom authentication plugin that implements the exact rules you want to be followed (or look in the list of existing 3rd-party authentication plugins to see if a suitable one already exists - https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=21 )
5. Lots of different options - Big Blue Button often mentioned, but I've not used it: https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=mod_bigbluebuttonbn
6. I believe Big Blue Button does this
7. Enrolment plugin 'PayPal' is included as standard in Moodle, you just need to enable it under site admin > plugins > enrolment
8. Edit the 'front page' settings and enable 'list of courses'.

Comment: Thank you.  But what about assigning roles (Teacher, Student) at the registration screen itself>  The version I use is 2.6.2

Comment: If you mean the at the point where you create an account for the site, then that doesn't make any sense - Moodle doesn't usually have 'teacher' users or 'student' users; you have users on the site who are teachers for a particular course, or students on a particular course. If you mean during enrolment in a course, you can create multiple self-enrolment instances for a course (optionally with passwords) and each with a different role associated with them.